# Which CMS meets the following requirements?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I'm looking to create a rather content-heavy (but low budgeted) website that is going to have a lot of different sections.

The post important requirement is that it be easy to user for the administrator who won't be very tech-savvy. What I'm looking for is to minimize them coming back to me whenever they want something on the website done (i.e. adding a contact form or something like that).

The website is, for the most part, going to be a simply two level design. Each 'section' (i.e. link the navbar) is either going to be a standalone page or a page that lists other pages in a section (these pages are what constitutes the second tier).

To give an example, the top tier may be:
Home | News | Events | Volunteer | About

Home and About will be standalone pages. News will list all sorted news items. Events will list events in a potentially arbitrary order (i.e. user-weighted). Volunteer will be a form that will send an email to the 'volunteer manager'.

These volunteer-type, data-entry forms are going to be used in multiple places throughout the website and I'd like it to be rather simple for users to create these forms and get the data back from them (either through email or a backend interface).Furthermore, a section should be capable of having both forms and normal pages.

I don't know how well written this post is but that's the gist of it. Normally I'd choose Drupal but I'm not sure the person managing the website is going to be able to use it without having to come back to me constantly (although I might revert to it depending on what's available).

I was wondering what other recommendations you guys have for a system that's easy and intuitive but powerful enough to handle what I listed above.

I should note that while I'd prefer it to be a PHP-based CMS any open-source CMS should suffice for this project.

Comment: Let the person who will be managing the site have a look at [Drupal Gardens](http://www.drupalgardens.com) first. See if he can cope with that, and if so, go for Drupal 7...

Answer (score 2):

I did a usability study of different CMS systems in college and I'd like to share with you some of my findings:

After evaluating three systems, an average was taken of their usability problem severity ratings for each category for each system (0 being no problem at all, 5 being severe usability problems). Drupal had an average rating of 1.7, Joomla had an average rating of 1.5, and PHP-Fusion had an average rating of 1.2.

My recommendation for beginners is PHP-Fusion since the interface is very easy to learn. Intermediate to advanced users should use Drupal for its huge collection of features and extensions. But if one wants a middle ground between simple and feature-rich, Joomla would be the best system for that purpose.

If you're interested in the full study, I can email it to you.

Comment: The heuristics I used were based on Jakob Nielsen's Ten Usability Heuristics: http://www.useit.com/papers/heuristic/heuristic_list.html

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought would be Drupal but you have already mentioned it as probably being too complicated.

I know most web developers will flinch at event the mention of this, but have you considered Wordpress?  Some of the custom themes are pretty sophisticated and mimic a CMS pretty well.  The advantage of wordpress is that it would be very easy to maintain for someone who has no knowledge of php.

Comment: Do you know of any examples of 'sophisticated' WordPress sites? If it meets what I'm after, I'm more than happy to give it a go.

Comment: There are a load of examples out there. A google search for 'wordpress cms themes' returns a huge number of resources.  You will find that some of the more sophisticated ones are commercial but some of them have a very good reputation behind them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd still say go with Drupal; just carefully create a role for the main user of the site and *don't* give them full admin access.  That way they are shielded from the full complexity (and from screwing things up).

Answer (score 0):

Joomla is what i would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress sounds like the best idea. It's free open source and PHP.

Check out [Contact form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) for your contact forms, as they are very customisable.